# How to upload file with python mechanicalsoup to ASP.net site inside a form

Tags: python, asp.net, python-requests

I'm trying to automate the interaction of a website.  The website is built with ASP.net so most of the interactions work as a form under the hood.  One of the things I need to do is upload a file.  In Chrome's inspect window I see this part of the form:

```
ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$RPBVContent$ucPriceUploader$FileUpload1: (binary)
```

Chrome's inspect doesn't show the form information when I actually submit the file.  It only shows this when I try to upload without having selected the file.

I previously tried doing:

```
    with open('pricestoy.csv', 'rb') as f:
            pp=browser.submit_selected(files={'prices.csv': f})
```

but the website didn't seem to receive the file even though it returned a 200.

It seems like I need to do something like

```
    with open('pricestoy.csv', 'rb') as f:
            browser['ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$RPBVContent$ucPriceUploader$cmdUpload1']=f.read()
    pp=browser.submit_selected()
```

but that's got the same issue where I get a 200 but the site doesn't seem to recognize having got a file.

if I do `pp.request.headers` I see that the `Content-Length` is 6158289 but when I submit the file in Chrome then it has Content_Length of 6158414 so there seems to be something Chrome is adding.  I don't know if that matters since it's very close.

Another difference is that Chrome has

`Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryg4PYqQpHVnsxwtTh`

whereas the python version has

`Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=d5416a61760fabc3ac8e6f99229df131`

At this point I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very helpful thing in figuring this out was to use Firefox instead of Chrome.  Firefox has the option to 'Copy POST data' in its Inspect Network whereas Chrome doesn't.  By doing that I could see that I was trying to put the file into the wrong form id.  I could also see that boundary was just an arbitrary string so focusing on that was time wasted.  Also I found this deep in the documentation for mechanicalsoup:

> Example: uploading a file through a 
> field (provide the path to the local file, and its content will be
> uploaded):
>
> form.set("tagname", path_to_local_file)

So it turned out to be as simple as doing

```
browser.form.set('ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$RPBVContent$ucPriceUploader$FileUpload1', 'pricestoy.csv')
browser.submit_selected()
```